# I'm getting a 503 response from heroku

Tags: go, heroku

I deployed a golang web api to heroku. This go app used a go library with c++ codes. It worked well when I run `heroku local` but it returns

```
2021-03-26T13:37:10.544197+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/api" host=tg-web.herokuapp.com request_id=3c9ef743-fea4-49e1-8f3a-eb3c24530d76 fwd="101.87.172.181" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

C=0x7f2d4ca6e18b m=4 sigcode=18446744073709551610
2021-03-26T13:26:35.033707+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-26T13:26:35.033727+00:00 app[web.1]: goroutine 0 [idle]:
2021-03-26T13:26:35.033745+00:00 app[web.1]: runtime: unknown pc 0x7f2d4ca6e18b
2021-03-26T13:26:35.033807+00:00 app[web.1]: stack: frame={sp:0x7f2d487ae4e0, fp:0x0} stack=[0x7f2d477af288,0x7f2d487aee88)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.033812+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae3e0:  2d33302d31323032  36323a3331203632
2021-03-26T13:26:35.033812+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae3f0:  706d742f2035333a  742f6e6f646f632f
2021-03-26T13:26:35.033823+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae400:  65686361632f706d  687461702d6f672f
2021-03-26T13:26:35.033845+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae410:  646f6d2f676b702f  2e6275687469672f
2021-03-26T13:26:35.033876+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae420:  00007f2d4cc14643  00007f2d4cc14644
2021-03-26T13:26:35.033895+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae430:  00007f2d4cc14643  0000000000000000
2021-03-26T13:26:35.033916+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae440:  00007f2d4cc14644  0000000000000000
2021-03-26T13:26:35.033938+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae450:  796e61792f6d6f63  696a6f672f757769
2021-03-26T13:26:35.033976+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae460:  00007f2d4cc14643  00007f2d4cc14644
2021-03-26T13:26:35.033983+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae470:  00007f2d4cc14643  0000000000000000
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034078+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae480:  00007f2d4cc14644  0000000000000000
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034078+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae490:  796e61792f6d6f63  696a6f672f757769
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034081+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae4a0:  2d33302d31323032  36323a3331203632
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034101+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae4b0:  706d742f2035333a  742f6e6f646f632f
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034120+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae4c0:  65686361632f706d  687461702d6f672f
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034139+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae4d0:  646f6d2f676b702f  2e6275687469672f
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034180+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae4e0: <0000000000000000  2e64656c69616620
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034218+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae4f0:  000000000000001c  0000000000000000
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034267+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae500:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034305+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae510:  0000001f00000002  0000000000000005
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034313+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae520:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034350+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae530:  0000000000000000  0000000000000003
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034353+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae540:  0000000000000008  0000000000000000
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034370+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae550:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034396+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae560:  fffffffe7fffffff  ffffffffffffffff
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034409+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae570:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034426+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae580:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034443+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae590:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034459+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae5a0:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034495+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae5b0:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034523+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae5c0:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034554+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae5d0:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034557+00:00 app[web.1]: runtime: unknown pc 0x7f2d4ca6e18b
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034590+00:00 app[web.1]: stack: frame={sp:0x7f2d487ae4e0, fp:0x0} stack=[0x7f2d477af288,0x7f2d487aee88)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034609+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae3e0:  2d33302d31323032  36323a3331203632
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034646+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae3f0:  706d742f2035333a  742f6e6f646f632f
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034679+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae400:  65686361632f706d  687461702d6f672f
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034718+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae410:  646f6d2f676b702f  2e6275687469672f
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034755+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae420:  00007f2d4cc14643  00007f2d4cc14644
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034784+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae430:  00007f2d4cc14643  0000000000000000
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034815+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae440:  00007f2d4cc14644  0000000000000000
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034831+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae450:  796e61792f6d6f63  696a6f672f757769
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034847+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae460:  00007f2d4cc14643  00007f2d4cc14644
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034872+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae470:  00007f2d4cc14643  0000000000000000
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034891+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae480:  00007f2d4cc14644  0000000000000000
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034921+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae490:  796e61792f6d6f63  696a6f672f757769
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034940+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae4a0:  2d33302d31323032  36323a3331203632
2021-03-26T13:26:35.034975+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae4b0:  706d742f2035333a  742f6e6f646f632f
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035003+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae4c0:  65686361632f706d  687461702d6f672f
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035031+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae4d0:  646f6d2f676b702f  2e6275687469672f
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035056+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae4e0: <0000000000000000  2e64656c69616620
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035073+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae4f0:  000000000000001c  0000000000000000
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035106+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae500:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035123+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae510:  0000001f00000002  0000000000000005
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035144+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae520:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035178+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae530:  0000000000000000  0000000000000003
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035188+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae540:  0000000000000008  0000000000000000
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035205+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae550:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035230+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae560:  fffffffe7fffffff  ffffffffffffffff
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035249+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae570:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035281+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae580:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035306+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae590:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035344+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae5a0:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035392+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae5b0:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035432+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae5c0:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035468+00:00 app[web.1]: 00007f2d487ae5d0:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035468+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035488+00:00 app[web.1]: goroutine 19 [syscall]:
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035540+00:00 app[web.1]: runtime.cgocall(0x756a70, 0xc00013f780, 0x7da6a0)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035622+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/go1.12.17/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:128 +0x5b fp=0xc00013f750 sp=0xc00013f718 pc=0x40bc6b
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035633+00:00 app[web.1]: github.com/yanyiwu/gojieba._Cfunc_NewJieba(0x7f2d40000b60, 0x7f2d40000bd0, 0x7f2d40000c40, 0x7f2d40000cb0, 0x7f2d40000d10, 0x0)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035770+00:00 app[web.1]: _cgo_gotypes.go:220 +0x4e fp=0xc00013f780 sp=0xc00013f750 pc=0x75118e
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035881+00:00 app[web.1]: github.com/yanyiwu/gojieba.NewJieba(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.035946+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/go-path/pkg/mod/github.com/yanyiwu/gojieba@v1.1.2/jieba.go:37 +0x240 fp=0xc00013f878 sp=0xc00013f780 pc=0x751710
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036038+00:00 app[web.1]: github.com/z-t-y/tennessgo.Translate.Translate(0xc000122060, 0x21, 0xb38cc0, 0xec, 0xec, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036082+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/go-path/pkg/mod/github.com/z-t-y/tennessgo@v0.0.0-20210326131003-1a8a4ba361a5/tenness.go:164 +0x369 fp=0xc00013fa90 sp=0xc00013f878 pc=0x754449
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036121+00:00 app[web.1]: main.handleAPIPost(0x8bafe0, 0xc00011c0e0, 0xc000116100, 0x0, 0xc0000fc240)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036177+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/build_f954dda9/server.go:86 +0x16e fp=0xc00013fb68 sp=0xc00013fa90 pc=0x7563de
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036198+00:00 app[web.1]: main.handleAPIRequest(0x8bafe0, 0xc00011c0e0, 0xc000116100)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036257+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/build_f954dda9/server.go:56 +0x22c fp=0xc00013fbe8 sp=0xc00013fb68 pc=0x755f0c
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036278+00:00 app[web.1]: net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x84bae0, 0x8bafe0, 0xc00011c0e0, 0xc000116100)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036306+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/go1.12.17/go/src/net/http/server.go:1995 +0x44 fp=0xc00013fc10 sp=0xc00013fbe8 pc=0x6f99a4
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036351+00:00 app[web.1]: net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0xc00001e400, 0x8bafe0, 0xc00011c0e0, 0xc000116100)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036391+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/go1.12.17/go/src/net/http/server.go:2375 +0x1d6 fp=0xc00013fc70 sp=0xc00013fc10 pc=0x6fb8a6
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036435+00:00 app[web.1]: github.com/rs/cors.(*Cors).Handler.func1(0x8bafe0, 0xc00011c0e0, 0xc000116100)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036491+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/go-path/pkg/mod/github.com/rs/cors@v1.7.0/cors.go:219 +0x1b8 fp=0xc00013fcc8 sp=0xc00013fc70 pc=0x72e288
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036523+00:00 app[web.1]: net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc00000e2e0, 0x8bafe0, 0xc00011c0e0, 0xc000116100)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036558+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/go1.12.17/go/src/net/http/server.go:1995 +0x44 fp=0xc00013fcf0 sp=0xc00013fcc8 pc=0x6f99a4
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036579+00:00 app[web.1]: net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc000084a90, 0x8bafe0, 0xc00011c0e0, 0xc000116100)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036601+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/go1.12.17/go/src/net/http/server.go:2774 +0xa8 fp=0xc00013fd20 sp=0xc00013fcf0 pc=0x6fcc78
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036624+00:00 app[web.1]: net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc0001020a0, 0x8bb6e0, 0xc00010a140)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036654+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/go1.12.17/go/src/net/http/server.go:1878 +0x851 fp=0xc00013ffc8 sp=0xc00013fd20 pc=0x6f8961
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036659+00:00 app[web.1]: runtime.goexit()
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036699+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/go1.12.17/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1337 +0x1 fp=0xc00013ffd0 sp=0xc00013ffc8 pc=0x4607d1
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036701+00:00 app[web.1]: created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036735+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/go1.12.17/go/src/net/http/server.go:2884 +0x2f4
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036735+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036736+00:00 app[web.1]: goroutine 1 [IO wait]:
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036771+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/poll.runtime_pollWait(0x7f2d46772f08, 0x72, 0x0)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036777+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/go1.12.17/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:182 +0x56
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036814+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/poll.(*pollDesc).wait(0xc000014118, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0, 0x830718)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036825+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/go1.12.17/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:87 +0x9b
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036847+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/poll.(*pollDesc).waitRead(...)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036851+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/go1.12.17/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:92
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036897+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/poll.(*FD).Accept(0xc000014100, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036918+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/go1.12.17/go/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:384 +0x1ba
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036927+00:00 app[web.1]: net.(*netFD).accept(0xc000014100, 0xc000024a70, 0xc000024a00, 0x4143c9)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036949+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/go1.12.17/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:238 +0x42
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036966+00:00 app[web.1]: net.(*TCPListener).accept(0xc000010040, 0xc0000b9d38, 0x1f1ae9fb, 0xcd5048904c19853e)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.036998+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/go1.12.17/go/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go:139 +0x32
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037008+00:00 app[web.1]: net.(*TCPListener).AcceptTCP(0xc000010040, 0xc0000b9d60, 0x4b7796, 0x605de10b)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037039+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/go1.12.17/go/src/net/tcpsock.go:247 +0x48
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037072+00:00 app[web.1]: net/http.tcpKeepAliveListener.Accept(0xc000010040, 0xc0000b9db0, 0x18, 0xc000000180, 0x6fd124)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037076+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/go1.12.17/go/src/net/http/server.go:3264 +0x2f
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037117+00:00 app[web.1]: net/http.(*Server).Serve(0xc000084a90, 0x8bb1e0, 0xc000010040, 0x0, 0x0)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037118+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/go1.12.17/go/src/net/http/server.go:2859 +0x22d
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037145+00:00 app[web.1]: net/http.(*Server).ListenAndServe(0xc000084a90, 0xc000084a90, 0x1)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037149+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/go1.12.17/go/src/net/http/server.go:2797 +0xe4
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037153+00:00 app[web.1]: net/http.ListenAndServe(...)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037162+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/go1.12.17/go/src/net/http/server.go:3037
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037169+00:00 app[web.1]: main.main()
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037201+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/build_f954dda9/server.go:31 +0x20a
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037202+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037208+00:00 app[web.1]: goroutine 20 [runnable]:
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037216+00:00 app[web.1]: net/http.(*connReader).backgroundRead(0xc0000fc1e0)
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037263+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/go1.12.17/go/src/net/http/server.go:676
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037264+00:00 app[web.1]: created by net/http.(*connReader).startBackgroundRead
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037264+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/go1.12.17/go/src/net/http/server.go:673 +0xca
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037268+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037270+00:00 app[web.1]: rax    0x0
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037276+00:00 app[web.1]: rbx    0x7f2d487af700
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037302+00:00 app[web.1]: rcx    0x7f2d4ca6e18b
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037302+00:00 app[web.1]: rdx    0x0
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037305+00:00 app[web.1]: rdi    0x2
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037309+00:00 app[web.1]: rsi    0x7f2d487ae4e0
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037315+00:00 app[web.1]: rbp    0x7f2d4cf62360
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037320+00:00 app[web.1]: rsp    0x7f2d487ae4e0
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037325+00:00 app[web.1]: r8     0x0
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037351+00:00 app[web.1]: r9     0x7f2d487ae4e0
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037352+00:00 app[web.1]: r10    0x8
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037355+00:00 app[web.1]: r11    0x246
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037358+00:00 app[web.1]: r12    0x7f2d4cf63700
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037364+00:00 app[web.1]: r13    0x7f2d487ae740
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037370+00:00 app[web.1]: r14    0x7f2d40000fa0
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037375+00:00 app[web.1]: r15    0x7f2d487aedb0
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037380+00:00 app[web.1]: rip    0x7f2d4ca6e18b
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037386+00:00 app[web.1]: rflags 0x246
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037391+00:00 app[web.1]: cs     0x33
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037397+00:00 app[web.1]: fs     0x0
2021-03-26T13:26:35.037420+00:00 app[web.1]: gs     0x0
```

when i get the `tg-web.herokuapp.com/api`(the actual url for my app).

So is it the problem that herokuapp.com servers don't come with a c++ compiler?

Also, I'm using Go 1.16.2 on my own machine and Go 1.12.7 in heroku server.

Any suggestions?

Project url: https://github.com/z-t-y/tennessgo-web

P.S.
Problem fixed by using `gcc:latest` in Dockerfile.